# unmute a muted iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I just want to unmuted when I click on a muted iframe.
I autoplay the iframe muted but when I click on it I want to unmuted

**JS**

```
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
    videoId: 'DfwihPa9Rwk', // YouTube Video ID
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 0,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 0,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 0,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0,  // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0,        // Hide video controls when playing
      rel:0,              //Hide relation videos on finish
      mute:1              //Mute the video on start
    },
    events: {

  }
});
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you have tried already? Now it looks like you want us to make your application.

Comment: I've tried with addEventListener and with the events on the functiononYouTubeIframeAPIReady, and none works